# What is the difference between "accept" and "except"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What are the differences in usage between *accept* and *except* in standard English?

> Ex: I *accept* your offer of the book.

Comment: If you want to ask a question about two words, you need to show that you at least understand their basic definitions, and explain why you are still confused about which word would be used when. A "What is the difference is usage" question is acceptable, but, when the words aren't synonymous, you simply use the right word.

Comment: Try to show your research in your questions. Like did you try to find out their meanings first? Did you not understand their meanings? What exactly did you not understand?

Comment: At first it was necessary to translate these words into your native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Except](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/except) and [accept](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accept) are pronounced in the same way, but their definitions are definitely different.

Except is used when something doesn't follow a pattern. For example:

> The bank closes at 5, except on Friday when it closes at 6.

Accept, on the other hand, is to take or receive something that is given. For example:

> The graduate accepted the diploma.

Comment: They might be pronounced the same way in your particular, part of the world but, that is not the case everywhere. They are definitely not in England and the rest of the UK.

Comment: Accept - /əkˈsɛpt/ (UK & US), except - /ɛˈksɛpt/ (UK), /ɪˈksɛpt/ (US)... not the same at all.